# DataGrid to DataRowView  

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datarow

I need charged the item value from a dataGrid when user click on, into a datarowview to take the first value "IdEmployee" and assign to a variable.

This is my method, the problem is my variable dataRowView is Null!

How can I fix this?

```
private void _employeedataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView dataRowView = _employeedataGrid.CurrentCell.Item as DataRowView;
    var idEmployee = Convert.ToInt32(dataRowView.Row[0]);

    .......
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have same problem in WPF? Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

That is because `_employeedataGrid.CurrentCell.Item` cannot be cast as a `DataRowView`. Why don't you try `CurrentRow` instead of `CurrentCell`?:

```
private void _employeedataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView dataRowView = _employeedataGrid.CurrentRow.Item as DataRowView;
    var idEmployee = Convert.ToInt32(dataRowView.Row[0]);
    .......
}
```

Comment: I'm working with Wpf, and not have the "CurrentRow" option.. what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

That's what you need

```
DataRowView view = _employeedataGrid.Items[_employeedataGrid.SelectedIndex] as DataRowView;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            //during datagrid events like RowEditEnding, SelectionChange event 'e' will be very useful as...
            DataGridRow row1 = e.Row;
            int row_index = ((DataGrid)sender).ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(row1);

            //or try this if works
            int i_row = e.Row.GetIndex();
```

Comment: Consider editing your question and adding some text describing how your answer addresses the problem, it will make your answer more useful to the original poster and others.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the item is selected, you can get the values for each column directly without going through a loop. Column 1 will have an index Row.ItemArray[0], column 2 will have an index Row.ItemArray[1] etc. It all depends on your mission.

```
var EmpID = Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)_employeedataGrid.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
```